# Can inheritance be implemented into affecting methods in subclasses?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, pygame

I am currently developing a pygame game. There are two classes. One is Mass, other is Ball. Ball is a subclass for Mass.

Every object I create will be inherited from Mass. It is a base class. In the objects I create, I designed the `move` methods to implement gravity. But the thing I am trying to accomplish is to provide this gravity **(Basically a negative acceleration value defined in the method)** in the `Mass` class. So avoid repetition by coding this in all `move` methods.

So should I define another `move` method in `Mass`. Would the subclass' method override it ? My attempts at finding a solution to this have failed so far. So I am not asking you to write a code for me, I kindly request if you could just point me at the right direction, maybe tell me what I should explore, I will be grateful.

```
class Mass(object):
    # The base class

class Ball(Mass):

    def __init__(self, surface, radius, color, starting_pos):
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.starting_pos = starting_pos
        self.surface = surface

    def move(self):
        # Keyboard handlers

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, self.color, (self.starting_pos), self.radius )
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the call to `move()` in the subclasses that override it won't call by default the Mass' one. You can still explicitly call the parent method through inside the subclass implementation of it.

```
class Ball(Mass):
  #...
  def move(self):
    Mass.move(self)
    #...
```

What you are doing here when you call `ballInstance.move()` is just getting the unbound `Mass.move` method and invoking it with the Ball instance `ballInstance`. This is a nice way to see the explicit `self` argument in action.

Comment: Or, more generally, `super` can be used to call a method on an object's superclass.

Comment: So this way of calling methods is actually a way to copy the source code of that method ? Is it the same thing ?

Comment: No copy of source code. This is an explicit call to the `Mass.move` method.

Comment: I guess you could think about it that way, but they are distinct methods. This it just a way to access an overwritten method.

Comment: I can add more features after calling that method right ?

Comment: It is a call to a function/method like any other, it just happens to be from the superclass.

Answer (score 2):

If gravity would be shared between all Mass objects why wouldn't it be a class attribute?  As well you can call `Mass.move` from subclasses:

```
class Mass(object):
    gravity = -9.8
    def move(self):
       #generic movement
    # The base class

class Ball(Mass):
    ...
    def move(self):
        Mass.move(self)#run the one defined in Mass
        #then do anything extra
        print(self.gravity)
```

that way the constant is shared between all objects and any subclass can still rely on common code in Mass.